# Portal Server is too heavy as a solution

Tags: jakarta-ee, frameworks, enterprise-portal

Hi I have an application to be designed and am contemplating whether to build it as JSR compliant portlets to be deployed on a portal server or as a normal Java web application.

The requirements do not mandate a lot of the portal like features, but only few such as : the individual components needs to be designed as widgets which can be plugged in to a page and configured by the administrator. The Administrator should also be able to decide the target  pages at run time and should be able to manage the components that needs to be placed in a page and should have control over the layout.

I know these requirements are easily met by a portal server and designing the components individually as portlets, but is there any alternative framework or set of frameworks which can help in achieving above two and still be light weight as a packaged solution.

Some thing like - Spring + Tiles + Velocity templates ??